# Django takes too long to render dictionary

Tags: django, django-templates

Am using django to render a dictionary to the template. The dictionary have some 150k records. It takes more than 30 secs to render the template. I cannot lazy load the data and I need that entire data to be passed to my template in once. Is there any way to render the template in lesser time?

This is my view.

```
def report(request):
   data = mydict()   #returns my dictionary
   return render(request,'app/report.html',{ 'content' : data})
```

Comment: Are you displaying the 150k of data at once, or maybe are you paginating it at the template?

Comment: Am displaying all the data at once as a js tree.

Comment: You need to give more information about what the data is and how it is generated. Is it coming from the db? Is it generated in one db hit or many?

Comment: How are you so sure that the rendering is the lag, and not the DB query response?

Comment: Am querying my data from S3. It's a text file and am constructing a dictionary using the contents of the file. the size of the text file is 20MB.

Comment: Am sure that the rendering is lag because I printed the time utilized for querying and generating the dictionary. It's only 2 secs

Comment: Try using a profiler and add the output to your question: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html or if you are using Django debug_toolbar, could you add some performance stats from there?

Comment: Using the django toolbar, the time utilized to render the template is 20694.84MS